# Amsterdam to Bollenstreek with Day Pass

Tags: tickets, europe, netherlands, amsterdam

Can I use the 24 hr day ticket from Amsterdam (8.5 euros) to travel from Amsterdam central station to Bollenstreek? If not, what’s the ideal way to reach there?

I read on a blog that Bollenstreek is just a 20mins trip from Amsterdam but on Google Maps it shows about 1 hour.

Comment: I guess the 20 minutes refer to the train ride,while your one hour is to some particular place that is not a train station. (An hour on a train takes you halfway across the Netherlands.)

Comment: Definitely not within 20 minutes by train. The shortest would be to Sassenheim and that is 35 minutes - bringing you to the edge of De Bollenstreek. Hillegom would be better but that requires a transfer in Haarlem (or Aerdenhout) and takes longer.
And as Willeke states below, the famous flower fields are out of season now. Best time to come is mid April (no stay away, those tourists are causing way too much traffic problems ;))

Answer (score 6):

I think you mean the €8.50 daypass from [this page.](https://www.amsterdamtips.com/transport-tickets)
That is one from the GVB, the Amsterdam city public transport company. Those passes are only valid on the transports from that company and I am sure that those do not go all the way to the 'Bollenstreek'.

There are other buses and those will have day tickets as well as one way or limited time tickets, or you can buy an OV card and load it with credit, you need €4.50 on it to use it, you check in when you get on, you tap it to the screen again when you are ready to leave the bus and the system takes off what you actually need to pay.

Depending on where you want to go you might find a train more suitable. Again you can buy tickets, (€1 extra for a one time card, €0.50 extra if you buy from a ticket window rather than a machine, and those do add up.) On your OV card you need at least €20 for a train ride, but the method is the same, check in and check out, the system takes the credit of the system.

Note of warning. The Bollenstreek is mostly a touristy destination in spring, by June most of the spring flowers will be gone, in July there will be only other kinds of flowers and not the famous coloured fields.

You can find more information on time tables on the [railway planner](https://www.ns.nl/en/journeyplanner/) and the [general public transport planner](https://9292.nl/en), which also have the prices of the tickets and might sell you a 'print it yourself' version of the tickets which do not cost the extra money I mentioned for the train tickets, bus tickets bought in the bus will also be more expensive than an OV chip card or printed tickets and chip payment cards may be needed to buy them with some companies.

If you have a GVB pass, [this planner](https://reisinfo.gvb.nl/en) has the option (in extra options) to select only GVB routes, so ones you can use your pass.

Answer (score 2):

The 24 hr Amsterdam ticket is only (as one would expect) valid in Amsterdam. You cannot use it to travel to places outside of Amsterdam.

The Bollenstreek is a region, so first you need to determine where you are actually going to. Once you know where you want to go you can plan you trip using google maps, or, if you want to use public transport, using the official public transport planner that you can find here: https://9292.nl/en

On this site you can just enter your start and destination points. The site can plan between any combination of public transport stops, points of interest and street addresses.

Comment: If it is the GVB 24 hours ticket, it is only valid on many of the Amsterdam transports, not even all of them.